How to determine the effective mass for multivariate dispersion relation?
Consider the 1D dispersion obtained by the tight-binding method:
$
E(k)=\epsilon_0-t\cos(ka)
$
$\epsilon_0$ is the on-site energy and $t$ is the hopping energy. To find the effective mass, you can Taylor expand the dispersion in the vicinity of $|k|=0$. The result is
$
E(k)\approx (\epsilon_0-2t)+ta^2k^2
$
Then, the effective mass is
$
m^*=\hbar^2/\left(\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial k^2}\right)=\frac{\hbar^2}{2ta^2}
$
But, what does the mean for multiple dimensions? For example, the tight-binding dispersion for a BCC lattice is
$
E(\vec{k})=\epsilon_0-8t[\cos(\frac{k_xa}{2})\cos(\frac{k_ya}{2})\cos(\frac{k_za}{2})]
$
Taylor expanding in the vicinity of $\Gamma$, you get
$
E(\vec{k})\approx\epsilon_0-t(8-k_x^2a^2)(8-k_y^2a^2)(8-k_z^2a^2)
$
How do you then determine the effective mass from the relation $m^*=\hbar^2/\left(\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial k^2}\right)$?
My initial thought was to use the inverted effective mass tensor, which is defined as
$
[M]_{ij}^{-1}=\frac{1}{\hbar^2}\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial k_i\partial k_j}
$
If I am not mistaken, the dispersion is parabolic and isotropic. Hence, you should be able to determine the effective mass from
$
M^{-1}=\frac{1}{m^*}I
$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $m^*$ is the effective mass. But, I kept getting unreasonable results. For example, I was getting non-zero terms for the off-diagonal elements of and the diagonal elements weren't constant (i.e., they were functions of $k_x$, $k_y$, or $k_z$).

Does this answer your question? Why is effective mass a tensor?

Yes, I believe that you must treat the effective mass as a tensor. The issue that I was having was the tensor wasn't diagonal as you'd expect for a parabolic, isotropic band. I was Taylor expanding the dispersion about $k_x$, $k_y$, and $k_z$ simultaneously. I think you can expand about each component independently and fix the others at 0... but I'm not sure about that.

Considering the second order Taylor expansion amounts to introducing $M$. It is symmetric by Schwarz' theorem, so you can diagonalise it in an orthonormal basis. These eigenvalues will give you the effective masses in each principal direction.
